# Check feed/post update from user's wall without calling (pulling) graph api periodically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know how to use graph api - `https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/feed|posts` to get user's and page's feed.

I also know that facebook provides an [subscription API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/subscription/). But I can not use it to check feeds of users i am interested but not our application users (ex: A super idol I am interested but who is not our application users. I want to check not only posts by him but also messages posted by his fans)

Is there a notification service to notify me (callback) the updating of user's feed, such that I don't need to pull graph api periodically to check the updating?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I want to check not only posts by him but also messages posted by his fans" and "but not our application users"

This sounds like a stalker app.  http://developers.facebook.com/policy/ Facebook says you are not allowed to do that.